# How to use VBA to fill formula, but make formula floating?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I didn't manage to find a solution to this.

So this is a macro to fill a formula for cells in an Excel Table.
The Table is one of those "automatic" Excel Tables, which is why the `VLOOKUP` formulas when I recorded macros look this one, instead of giving a cell reference.

I'm trying to make "Forecast 21" float, i.e. when I run the other macros, I add columns, copy other values, and fill formula in this this specific column (2 columns left of the last column, `Cells(2, Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count - 2)`, which is always Forecast. But I need this to be **Forecast 22** the next time I run the macro, and **Forecast 23** etc etc.

How can I do this? I  tried mixing R1C1 but it doesn't work.

Many thanks in advance!

```vb
    Cells(2, Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count - 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'RCC totalt'!$A$1:$AS$59,MATCH(RIGHT(Table5[[#Headers],[Forecast 21]],2),'RCC totalt'!$A$1:$BB$1,0),FALSE)"
```

Basically adding three columns, Forecast, utilization and Difference + the week number:

**Code to add 3 columns:**

```
Sub AddColumns()
'Keep One Empty Column to the Right
'Remove Conditional Formatting
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 1).EntireColumn.Copy
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 0).EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Insert Column
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).EntireColumn.Insert
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 1).Value = "Forecast " & Right(Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 2).Value, 2) + 1

Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).EntireColumn.Insert
'add "Utilization"
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 1).Value = "Utilization " & Right(Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 3).Value, 2) + 1
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).EntireColumn.Insert
'add "Difference"
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 1).Value = "Difference " & Right(Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 4).Value, 2) + 1

Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Cut
Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column - 3).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Comment: By _one of those "automatic" Excel Tables_ do you mean an Excel table?  i.e When you select a cell within the table you get a `Table Design` tab on the ribbon?

Comment: Could you provide more code please? A variable as the number might work. ```..."Forecast "& x ...    x=x+1``` but more code is needed.

Comment: Hi yes, precisely, an Excel Table where you get Table Design, and when you update the formula of one cell it automatically updates the others. 

I added the code to add three columns. Basically it VLOOKUPS the last two digit (i.e. the week number) in another sheet, and returns a value in this sheet. But i need it to change based on the week (i.e. the column). If i just fill formula now it will be stuck at 21.